# Why react-router-dom does not work in this code

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm studying react app and try to use react-router-dom.
I typed the "http://localhost:3000/" in the browser.
My expectation is "Home" is displayed in the browser.
However, as the browser render this code, nothing is displayed.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage} />
            <Route path='/Contact' component={ContactPage} />
            <Route path='/About' component={AboutPage} />
            <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

function HomePage() {
  return <h2>Home</h2>
}

function ContactPage() {
  return <h2>Contact</h2>
}

function AboutPage() {
  return <h2>About</h2>
}

function NotFoundPage() {
  return <h2>NotFoundPage</h2>
}

export default App;
```

I have no idea why it does not work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using router v6, you need use the `element` prop instead of `component`. But more importantly you need to instantiate the component (change `element={HomePage}` to `element={< HomePage />}`).

See the docs: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#defining-routes

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
            <Route path="/Contact" element={<ContactPage />} />
            <Route path="/About" element={<AboutPage />} />
            <Route component={<NotFoundPage />} />
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

function HomePage() {
  return <h2>Home</h2>;
}

function ContactPage() {
  return <h2>Contact</h2>;
}

function AboutPage() {
  return <h2>About</h2>;
}

function NotFoundPage() {
  return <h2>NotFoundPage</h2>;
}

export default App;
```